# How do I set preschedule=FALSE for llply's parallel mode?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, multicore, argument-passing

I want to use llply to perform some parallel computations using the multicore doParallel backend (i.e. `doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores=8)`), but each computation will take a different amount of time, so I want to set the multicore preschedule option to false for this computation. However, I'm unsure how to pass this option to `llply` which will pass it to `foreach` which will pass it to `doParallel` which will finally pass it to `mclapply`. Can anyone give an example of doing this?

In other words, how would I disable prescheduling in the following code?

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=2)
x <- llply(1:10, sqrt, .parallel=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the llply ".paropts" option to do that:

```
opts <- list(.options.multicore=list(preschedule=FALSE))
x <- llply(1:10, sqrt, .parallel=TRUE, .paropts=opts)
```

As you guessed, the ".paropts" option passes the ".options.multicore" option to foreach, which propagates it on to doParallel, which calls mclapply with `mc.preschedule=FALSE`.